# Logstash grok pattern not working as soon as round parentheses are included

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am using grok filter and my own regular expression patterns in Logstash to get certain log file contents into separate fields. This works well up to the point where I need to match round brackets. The patterns I try to use in Logstash work with every RegEx/Grok tester I could find in the internet, yet in Logstash they always lead to a grok parse failure.
Even something as simple as

`(?<fieldname>\(.*\))`

fails while

`(?<fieldname>\|.{7}\|)`

works.

Do those brackets need to be escaped somehow differently?

Comment: I think your grok pattern should work as `\` can be used for escaping. Can you share a log sample ?

Comment: Are you escaping the backslash in your config file? It should look like this: `match => { "message" => "(?<fieldname>\\(.*\\))" }`

Comment: Following your suggestions I tried `grok {
        match => {"message" => "(?<fieldname>\\(.*\\))"}
        }` and `grok {
        match => {"message" => "(?<fieldname>'\(.*\)')"}
        }` unfortunately both lead to the same grok parse failure.

Comment: A log entry would look like: `2020-12-18T01:00:42,859 | INFO  | Camel (routing.xml_m3statisticsrebuildvalidate_2_0.XML_M3StatisticsRebuildValidate) thread #82 - JmsConsumer[routing.stat.rebuild] | rg.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger  159 | 226 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.21.2 | Statistics XML successfully validated. Filename 'blabla'` and I need to get the string starting with routing.xml...Validate.

Comment: @ChrisSoars NB: When answering comment on your question, tag the people you're answering to with `@`, like I did, so that they get a notification.

Comment: I haven't been able to fix the issue, but if you are only interested in the string without the brackets, you can use this: `match => {"message" => "\((?<fieldname>.*)\)"}`. This will match the string between the bracket and get you what you need

Comment: Looking at your entry, perhaps the [dissect plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) might be a better idea, it should be faster than with grok and you wouldn't have to deal with the regex pitfalls.

Comment: @bauds Thank you, I copied your exact code but it results in parse failure once again. Does it work for you? It really seems that as soon as I try to use a regex formula containing round bracket it won't work. Other RegEx filter without those bracket's work (i.e. I was able to extract the loglevel between the two pipes). I will try dissect to see how it can help but there is other loglines I would like to apply lookahead/lookbehind RegEx formulars but those also involve round brackets and won't work for that reason. I wonder if this is some sort of bug?

Comment: [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/773234990657568860/790561863544864768/unknown.png)'s what I tested. Putting the brackets outside of the pattern did the trick for me. If it's a bug, maybe it's version-specific, I'm using logstash version 7.9.1 myself.

Comment: @baudsp Ok, not sure what I actually changed but I tried your formula once again and now I don't get a parse failure - which is good - but instead of the string contained in the brackets I get `"fieldname":"doAction=true"` as result. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: `Does that make any sense to you?` Well, that depends if it was present in the string you tested your filter with. If that's not the case, that doesn't make sense

Comment: @baudsp Doh, you are right: it was part of the log, I never noticed that beeing in there. Good news is: your suggestion works! Bad news is: I don't quite understand why, but I think I can still work with that.. Thanks a lot!